# Trouble compiling with GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, bioinformatics, libstdc++

Greeting!
Excuse me if this is a duplicate, but I have searched the net and did not found a solution.
Im trying to compile to install a software using make and the following error occurs:

```
g++ -Iseqan/include -pthread -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++14 -static-libstdc++ src/main.cpp src/utils.cpp src/io.cpp src/Settings.cpp src/Jellyfish.cpp src/Read.cpp src/Explorer.cpp src/Trail.cpp src/Trajectory.cpp -o talc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: talc] Error 1
```

The problem is the lstdc++, which does not seem to be installed. This is a little bit weird, as this seems a standard library.
In addition, there is no folder name "ld" in the usr/bin directory. I'm a total newbie with gcc and c++ in general, and I'm at loss on what to do.

Is there any method to install this library locally and redirect the path that the compiler searches there (I'm using a remote linux server) with do sudo permissions.

Additional info:
Makefile

```
CXX := $(if $(CXX),$(CXX),g++)
CXXFLAGS=-Iseqan/include -pthread -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++14 -static-libstdc++

srcs=src/main.cpp src/utils.cpp src/io.cpp src/Settings.cpp src/Jellyfish.cpp src/Read.cpp src/Explorer.cpp src/Trail.cpp src/Trajectory.cpp

talc: $(srcs)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(srcs) -o ta
```

gcc version: 8.3.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld` is not a "folder" (in POSIX this is called a "directory").  It's program.  It definitely exists.  Remember that `/usr/bin/ld` is NOT the same thing as `usr/bin/ld` (missing initial slash).  Second, you probably DO have the C++ runtime installed but only as a shared library.  When you say `-static-libstdc++` you want the static version which may not be installed.  If you remove the `-static-libstdc++` option does it work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/540875/1216776

Comment: @MadScientist You right! I was looking for a dir and not for a file, it is indeed under /usr/bin/. Also your suggestion did work. So just to make sure, removing the -static-libstdc++ only changed the library accessed by make, and it should not change anything in the compiled program?

Comment: Correct: it means that your program built with the shared library will get updates whenever the shared library is updated, rather than having the behaviour of the standard C++ library frozen at the time it was linked.  Most likely, that won't affect your program.

Comment: As Jonathan says it's highly unlikely you really need to link this statically.  That's typically only needed in situations where you want to compile your program on a system with a newer implementation of the C++ standard then copy the binary to another system with an older version and run it there.  If you find you really do want to do this, you'll have to investigate to discover which package contains the static versions of these libraries and install that.  Usually it's a *-dev* or *-devel* package; you don't say what distribution of Linux you're using.